# Laravel Blade Variable Variable

Tags: php, laravel

With Laravel 5.4, I am using a variable variable ($$var) in a blade template to access a model attribute. All the attributes work except the description attribute. Below is an example:

Model Migration:

```
Schema::create('user_roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name', 50);
    $table->string('description', 255);
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Controller:

```
...
$tableCols = [
    ['name' => 'id'],
    ['name' => 'name'],
    ['name' => 'description']
]
...
```

Blade NOT WORKING:

```
@foreach($tableCols as $tableCol)
    {{ $name = $tableCol['name']}}
    <td>{{ $model->$$name }} </td>
@endforeach
```

> Error: Undefined variable: description

Blade WORKING:

```
<td> {{ $model->name }} </td>
<td> {{ $model->description }} </td>
```

How do I get my variable variable $$ to get the description attribute. Thanks!

Comment: Try `$model->$name` instead.

Comment: @JohnEllmore Thanks put that as an answer and I will give you credit.